# Laravel - How to post data variables from 2 separate livewire component controllers, to a single blade file for CRUD functionality?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I wanted to post the variables initiated in the `MenuItemList.php` and `SubCategoryList.php` located in the App/Http/Livewire directory to a single blade file i.e. `menu-item.blade.php`. So I can further use the CRUD functionality for the above said tables i.e. `menu-items` and `sub-categories` from a single view, i.e. `menu-item.blade.php`.

When I run it through the different routes with separate views, it works flawlessly, but as soon as I try to combine them into one and try to view it all, in a single blade file, it gives me all sort of errors. Here is my source code.

App\Models\MenuItem.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MenuItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "menu_items";
    protected $fillable = ['sub_category_id', 'item_name', 'item_description'];
}
```

App\Http\Livewire\MenuItemList.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\MenuItem;

class MenuItemList extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search;
    public $itemId,$sub_category_id,$item_name,$item_description;
    public $isOpen = 0;

    public function render()
    {       
        $searchParams = '%'.$this->search.'%';

        return view('livewire.menu-item', [
            'menuitemlist' => MenuItem::where('item_name','like', $searchParams)->latest()->paginate(5)
        ]);
    }

    public function showModal() {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function hideModal() {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    public function store(){
        $this->validate(
            [   
                'sub_category_id' => 'required',
                'item_name' => 'required',
            ]
        );

        MenuItem::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->itemId], [
            'sub_category_id' => $this->sub_category_id,
            'item_name' => $this->item_name,
            'item_description' => $this->item_description
        ]);

        $this->hideModal();

        session()->flash('info', $this->itemId ? 'Post Update Successfully' : 'Post Created Successfully' );

        $this->itemId = '';
        $this->sub_category_id = '';
        $this->item_name = '';
        $this->item_description = '';
    }

    public function edit($id){
        $menuitem = MenuItem::findOrFail($id);
        $this->itemId = $id;
        $this->sub_category_id = $menuitem->sub_category_id;
        $this->item_name = $menuitem->item_name;
        $this->item_description = $menuitem->item_description;

        $this->showModal();
    }

    public function delete($id){
        MenuItem::find($id)->delete();
        session()->flash('delete','Post Successfully Deleted');
    }
}
```

App\Models\SubCategory.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SubCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "sub_categories";
    protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'sub_category_name'];
}
```

App\Http\Livewire\SubCategoryList.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\SubCategory;

class SubCategoryList extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search;
    public $itemId,$category_id,$sub_category_name;
    public $isOpen = 0;

    public function render()
    {       
        $searchParams = '%'.$this->search.'%';

        return view('livewire.sub-category', [
            'subcategorylist' => SubCategory::where('sub_category_name','like', $searchParams)->latest()->paginate(5)
        ]);
    }

    public function showModal() {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function hideModal() {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    public function store(){
        $this->validate(
            [   
                'category_id' => 'required',
                'sub_category_name' => 'required',
            ]
        );

        SubCategory::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->itemId], [
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,
            'sub_category_name' => $this->sub_category_name
        ]);

        $this->hideModal();

        session()->flash('info', $this->itemId ? 'Post Update Successfully' : 'Post Created Successfully' );

        $this->itemId = '';
        $this->category_id = '';
        $this->sub_category_name = '';
    }

    public function edit($id){
        $subcategory = SubCategory::findOrFail($id);
        $this->itemId = $id;
        $this->category_id = $subcategory->category_id;
        $this->sub_category_name = $subcategory->sub_category_name;

        $this->showModal();
    }

    public function delete($id){
        SubCategory::find($id)->delete();
        session()->flash('delete','Post Successfully Deleted');
    }
}
```

Routes\Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Livewire\MenuItemList;
use App\Http\Livewire\SubCategoryList;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/menu-item', MenuItemlist::class);
Route::get('/sub-category', SubCategorylist::class);

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

**EDITED**
Here is my `menu-item.blade.php` for referencing, I am using the exact same code for the `sub-category.blade.php`, just using the variables from the `SubCategory.php`. As I am unable to show them in a single view, I have made two separate views for the above said files.

Resources\Views\Livewire\menu-item.blade.php

```
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold leading-tight text-gray-800">
        Manage Menu Item
    </h2>
</x-slot>
        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="mx-auto max-w-5xl sm:px-6 lg:px-8">

                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow sm:rounded-lg px-4 py-4 my-8 text-sm">
                    
                    <div class="flex mb-4">
                        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                            <button wire:click="showModal()" class="px-4 py-2 my-3 font-bold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none">Create Menu Item</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                            <input wire:model="search" type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-2 my-3 text-blue-900 focus:outline-none" placeholder="Search Post...">           
                        </div>                     
                    </div>

                    @if($isOpen)
                         @include('livewire.create')
                    @endif

                    @if(session()->has('info'))
                        <div class="bg-green-500 border-2 border-green-600 rounded-b mb-2 py-3 px-3">
                            <div>
                                <h1 class="text-white font-bold">{{ session('info') }}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    @endif

                    @if(session()->has('delete'))
                        <div class="bg-red-500 border-2 border-red-600 rounded-b mb-2 py-3 px-3">
                            <div>
                                <h1 class="text-white font-bold">{{ session('delete') }}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    @endif
                             
                    <table class="w-full table-fixed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-gray-100">
                                <th class="w-20 px-4 py-2">Sr. No.</th>
                                <th class="px-4 py-2">Sub-Category ID</th>
                                <th class="px-4 py-2">Item Name</th>
                                <th class="px-4 py-2">Item Description</th>
                                <th class="px-4 py-2">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($menuitemlist as $key=>$menuitem)
                            <tr style="background-color: {{ $key % 2 == 0 ? '#fdfdfd': '#f5f5f5' }};">          
                                <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitemlist->firstitem() + $key }}</td>
                                <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitem->sub_category_id }}</td>
                                <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitem->item_name }}</td>
                                <td class="px-4 py-2">{{ $menuitem->item_description }}</td>
                                <td class="px-4 py-2">
                                    <button wire:click="edit({{ $menuitem->id }})" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-1 px-4 rounded">
                                    Edit
                                    </button>
                                    <button wire:click="delete({{ $menuitem->id }})" class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-1 px-4 rounded">
                                    Delete
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div class="mt-4">
                          {{$menuitemlist->links()}}
                    </div>
                   
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you share menu-item.blade.php markup?

Comment: @NajmusSakib Mate, I have added the source-code for the said file as well.